# kotlin compiler error while trying to run my flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, build.gradle

i recently changed version of my build.gradle to 7.4.2 because one of my dependencies wouldnt work without this version.after that i tried running my project,it took me hour to download resources and after that i got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not find kotlin-compiler-30.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.4.2/kotlin-compiler-30.4.2.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my whole resources got downloaded but only this single one keep showing up 2 second after i try to run it.via that link in error i managed to download "kotlin-compiler" but now i have no idea where should i post it,i would appreaciate it if someone tell me the location where i should put the kotlin compiler in it.it doesnt get downloaded no matter what i do so i want do it manually,where should i put it

Comment: Can you please try and open android project in android studio and post the error if you get there.